# Xcode failing to compile "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-lion, osx-snow-leopard, sigabrt

After compiling for the first time Xcode issued an error from Thread 1 about SIGABRT. The error log displayed this,

```
2012-11-18 20:26:37.866 Test app[26222:8a03] Unknown class 'AppDelegate', using 'NSObject' instead. Encountered in Interface Builder file at path /Users/tommiller/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test_app-gvobsrwxsylgvkamecrxetkkkorf/Build/Products/Debug/Test app.app/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/MainMenu.nib.
2012-11-18 20:26:37.908 Test app[26222:8a03] -[_NSControllerObjectProxy copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcfb8659660
2012-11-18 20:26:37.909 Test app[26222:8a03] An uncaught exception was raised
2012-11-18 20:26:37.909 Test app[26222:8a03] -[_NSControllerObjectProxy copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcfb8659660
2012-11-18 20:26:37.913 Test app[26222:8a03] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e42dfc6 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010e29bd5e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e4ba2ae -[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 190
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e41ae73 ___forwarding___ + 371
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e41ac88 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 232
    5   AppKit                              0x000000010eef3178 -[NSCell _setContents:] + 73
    6   AppKit                              0x000000010eef3055 -[NSCell setObjectValue:] + 160
    7   AppKit                              0x000000010f115adc -[_NSPlaceholderTextFieldPlugin showValue:inObject:] + 388
    8   AppKit                              0x000000010f0fdf31 -[NSValueBinder _adjustObject:mode:observedController:observedKeyPath:context:editableState:adjustState:] + 809
    9   AppKit                              0x000000010f0fdb74 -[NSValueBinder _observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:context:] + 303
    10  AppKit                              0x000000010f1158cf -[NSTextValueBinder _observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:context:] + 43
    11  AppKit                              0x000000010eeec777 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueBindingCreation) bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options:] + 591
    12  AppKit                              0x000000010eee5a89 -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:topLevelObjects:] + 1079
    13  AppKit                              0x000000010eedc09f loadNib + 322
    14  AppKit                              0x000000010eedb59c +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 217
    15  AppKit                              0x000000010eedb4b7 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibFile:externalNameTable:withZone:] + 141
    16  AppKit                              0x000000010eedb3fa +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:] + 364
    17  AppKit                              0x000000010f14e9b3 NSApplicationMain + 398
    18  Test app                            0x000000010e22de12 main + 34
    19  Test app                            0x000000010e22dde4 start + 52
)
2012-11-18 20:26:37.972 Test app[26222:8a03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_NSControllerObjectProxy copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcfb8659660'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e42dfc6 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010e29bd5e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e4ba2ae -[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 190
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e41ae73 ___forwarding___ + 371
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e41ac88 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 232
    5   AppKit                              0x000000010eef3178 -[NSCell _setContents:] + 73
    6   AppKit                              0x000000010eef3055 -[NSCell setObjectValue:] + 160
    7   AppKit                              0x000000010f115adc -[_NSPlaceholderTextFieldPlugin showValue:inObject:] + 388
    8   AppKit                              0x000000010f0fdf31 -[NSValueBinder _adjustObject:mode:observedController:observedKeyPath:context:editableState:adjustState:] + 809
    9   AppKit                              0x000000010f0fdb74 -[NSValueBinder _observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:context:] + 303
    10  AppKit                              0x000000010f1158cf -[NSTextValueBinder _observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:context:] + 43
    11  AppKit                              0x000000010eeec777 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueBindingCreation) bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options:] + 591
    12  AppKit                              0x000000010eee5a89 -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:topLevelObjects:] + 1079
    13  AppKit                              0x000000010eedc09f loadNib + 322
    14  AppKit                              0x000000010eedb59c +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 217
    15  AppKit                              0x000000010eedb4b7 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibFile:externalNameTable:withZone:] + 141
    16  AppKit                              0x000000010eedb3fa +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:] + 364
    17  AppKit                              0x000000010f14e9b3 NSApplicationMain + 398
    18  Test app                            0x000000010e22de12 main + 34
    19  Test app                            0x000000010e22dde4 start + 52
)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

And the signal is coming from `return NSApplicationMain(argc, (const char **)argv);` inside **main.m**,

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return NSApplicationMain(argc, (const char **)argv);
}
```

I rarely get these logged errors, so I have no clue to what the error is pointing to. My best guess is `14  AppKit 0x000000010eedb59c +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading)_loadNibFile:nameTable:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 217` is not loading the XIB?... **How can I fix this?**

Comment: A couple of debugging suggestions: set a breakpoint on Objective-C exceptions and enable zombies in the scheme you're using to run this.  Those steps may give better error messages.  I think you're right about something odd with the xib file but it's not yet clear what (bindings to a text field, perhaps?).

Comment: I did a breakpoint on the error point in main.m and got this, 0x109deade4:  movl   %eax, %edi

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the initial error:

```
Unknown class 'AppDelegate', using 'NSObject' instead. Encountered in Interface Builder file
```

It is telling you that somewhere in your code you tried to call a message selctor on an object that was assumed to be an AppDelegate but it was not. The error is to do when loading MainMenu.nib.

So it is probably not your code, but how your MainMenu view is wired in to the project. You want to open up your MainMenu XIB file and check if the delegate it wired to the app.

Comment: Where would I view that in IB?

Comment: Right click on File Owner, and look at the Outlets for the delegate.

Comment: It's pointing to AppDelegate. I got it to work. All I did was remake the XIB file. Strange! But I get a message saying "The managed object model version used to open the persistent store is incompatible with the one that was used to create the persistent store." after the compile and the app seems to work. That I believe is in my code...